# Create route in Apache ServiceMix Bundle:List state is Grace Period

Tags: apache-camel, apache-servicemix

I create a route on apache servicemix and put it in deploy. When the server started and I check the bundle:list it says that my route is in Grace Period and it's not working.
Currently I'm routing ftp to file server and do this format.

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <route>
          <from uri="FTP:username@//hostname /DB?password=password"/>
          <to uri="file:\\storage\folder\anotherFolder\anotherFolder\anotherFolder\"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
```

I did not input the exact credentials I use but that is the format that I used.

Is there any problem with my code or it's on my apache service mix? Please help I doing this for a week.

P.S. It works when its file to file server

Comment: Looks like your bundle waiting for something to start working. Try "diag bundle_number" or simply restart your bundle and read logs, there will be info about start problems.

Comment: What supposed to be meaning of this error? Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error resolving artifact org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jsch:jar:0.1.54_1: [Could not transfer artifact org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jsch:jar:0.1.54_1 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/):

Comment: All is written in exception message. Karaf can't download   org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jsch:jar from maven repository cause IOException.

Comment: How can I download it?

Comment: It will be endless loop of basic questions. I don't think that this is good place for it. You should read documentation about karaf for basic knowledge. About jar -  you shouldn't download anything by your self.  Find file org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg and check there URLs for maven repo. Try to check accessibility and find reason of IOException.

Comment: And if it works file-to-file, try to install camel-ftp feature in servicemix and change "FTP" to lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

You can install ftp using `feature:install camel-ftp` .